# why can't we use an integer to string direct conversion but can do bitwise to string?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

```
string binary = std::bitset<16>(15).to_string();//This cast is valid
int a=5;
string s=a.to_string()//this givees error
```

why does this is not valid?
is there any limitation on  to_string?

Comment: Use [`std::to_string(a)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) instead.

Comment: thanks for that . but my doubt is if that first conversion is right then why does not second one is also correct?

Comment: The second isn't a _conversion_. As it's told you in the answer, intrinsic types don't have any functions.

Comment: the first one is not a cast either

Comment: thanks @πάνταῥεῖ .

Comment: @phuclv,then what exactly should i call it ?

Comment: @Umesh _"what exactly should i call it ?"_ a class function call.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks. by conversion what i meant was creating a new string from that of bitset. My wordings were not proper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int` is a primitive type in C++, not a class type, and as such, it doesn't define any member functions such as `int::to_string();`. You should try the non-member `std::string std::to_string(int)`, to be used as: `string s = std::to_string(a);`

EDIT: `std::bitset` *does* define a member function `to_string` (see the documentation [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_string)), which is used to return simply a string of characters representing the bit pattern, and not the number as a stringified integer. If you do want to convert a `std::bitset` to a `std::string` representing the number as an *integer*, you could try the following:

```
auto bits = std::bitset<16>(15);
std::string s = std::to_string(bits.to_ulong());
```

Comment: This  kind off cleared my doubt. so int being primitive raised this problem,so does it mean that bitset supports  .to_string() operation?

Comment: @Umesh Bhat Yes: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_string

Answer (score 0):

`to_string` is a member function of `std::bitset`.  There is no `to_string` member of `int`.

A `to_string` function for numeric types is provided in `<string>`.  You would use it like this:

```
int a=5;
string s=to_string(a);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy.